I use MPI in my section I always have the array always have garbage value
I have a problem with using scatter in mpi
this is my code I have a matrix n*m when the process id is 0 I enter the n and m and put values in arr the broadcast n and m to other process and I use scatter to divide the matrix on them and I recive the value of matrix in temp arr and I don't know if arr has a garbage value or temp don't recive the values it shoud find the max value in the matrix
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     int id, np;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id); // return the id of the process
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np); // return the number of processes
    int n, m;
    int **arr;
    int **temp;
    if(id == 0) {
        printf("enter n and m\n");
        cin >> n >> m;

        arr = new int*[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[m];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = i + j;
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    temp = new int*[n/np];
    for(int i = 0; i < n/np; i++) {
        temp[i] = new int[m];
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Scatter(&arr, (n/np) * m, MPI_INT, &temp[0][0], (n/np) * m, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("temp from id %d n-> %d  m->%d \n", id,n,m);
    for(int i = 0; i < n/np; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", temp[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int mx = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n/np; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            mx = max(mx, temp[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int ans;
    MPI_Reduce ( &mx, &ans, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0,  MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    if(id == 0) {
        printf("the max is %d\n", ans);
    }


    return 0;
}


Your arrays are not contiguous memory, you cannot send them with MPI this way.

can you tell how to send it ?

you really want to change the way you allocate your 2D array (incidentally you won't have to change MPI_Scatter())

I have not used mpi, but if the issue is dynamic array allocation and making it contiguous, see this answer.  To be honest, you chose one of the worst ways to dynamically create a 2D array using an int**, regardless of whether you are mpi or not.

with the latest C++, mdspan can do that for you and it is pretty straightforward https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan. It has been backported for other implementations of the standard and is available at https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan.
